# How to get date diff from date in the database and date now?

Tags: mysql

I'm new in MySql, what I want is get date from database and then get different from date now, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SELECT `pro_masastr` FROM `i2n_profiler_users` WHERE `userid` = 725, NOW()) AS DiffDate
```

but these query return error message.

Comment: can you post also the error?

Comment: you don't need for the subquery in `DATEDIFF` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`pro_masastr`, NOW()) as DiffDate
FROM `i2n_profiler_users`
WHERE `userid` = 725;
```

This is no need for the additional subquery.  Note thate `datediff()` is `expr1 - expr2`, so you might want the arguments in the other order:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), `pro_masastr`) as DiffDate
FROM `i2n_profiler_users`
WHERE `userid` = 725;
```

Comment: yes, that is what i want, thank you very much, you save my day.

Comment: Why use ``` instead of `'` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), 'pro_masastr') as DiffDate
FROM i2n_profiler_users
WHERE userid = SOME_ID_HERE;
```